# mousewheel scroll down doesn't work when mouse is on the grid - ui-grid angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, vertical-scrolling

For my Angular js grid work, I am using ui-grid(v3.1.1) to implement the grid table. When I change the pagination size, I am having trouble to scroll down using mousewheel. When I hover over the mouse on scrollbar, then scroll up and down both are working fine. Strangely, the scroll up using mousewheel is working fine too. Its just the scroll down that doesn't seem to work. I fail to understand the reason for it.

I have disabled the scrolling when not required using:

```
.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-viewport {
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
```

Other than this I have not changed any of the default settings. Why is it that the mousewheel scroll down won't work when hovered over ui-grid? Please help

Comment: I also have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I commented out `event.preventDefault()` on line 2859 of v4.0.2 (in `gridUtil.on.mousewheel` function).

Can't say what other impact this may have, but worked for my usage.

Comment: This is probably one of the better approaches as `uiGrid` has completely broken scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this - **if the grid has no scroll at least** - is to redefine the prototype function atTop & atBottom on uigrid's ScrollEvent. This will not need changes to uigrid's code, one just has to inject *ScrollEvent* in the controller or app.run().
The grid swallows any scroll event if its possible to scroll, but does not handle it if there are no scrollbars present.
The original code also fails an isNaN check on *this.y.percentage* - i think it should be as it is in the comment below.

```
 ScrollEvent.prototype.atTop = function(scrollTop) {
   return true;
   //return (this.y && (this.y.percentage === 0 || isNaN(this.y.percentage) || this.verticalScrollLength < 0) && scrollTop === 0);
 };

 ScrollEvent.prototype.atBottom = function(scrollTop) {
   return true;
   //return (this.y && (this.y.percentage === 1 || isNaN(this.y.percentage) || this.verticalScrollLength === 0) && scrollTop > 0);
 };
```

Comment: this solution works for me but the downside is that all grids are NOT gonna handle scroll. To solve this issue I'm doing a conditional check since "atTop" and "atBottom" functions can access grid scope (this.grid.appScope). Therefore the two methods can work according to the every single grid and not globally.

Comment: Yeah this a good solution! The `preventDefaults()` `uiGrid` is based on if you're at the bottom and has no checks for if you've disabled scrollbars, while there is no `GridOption` for disabling scroll listeners.

As for breaking other grids, they should never have been messing with scroll to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this mousewheel/trackpad drag issue in v4.0.2 & v4.0.3 in a grid with pagination & filtering enabled and with CSS modifications to enable cell word-wrap.

```
.ui-grid-viewport .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal !important;
  overflow:visible;
}

.ui-grid-cell {
  display : table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position: static;
}

.ui-grid-row {
  height: auto !important;
  display : table-row;
  position: static;
}

.ui-grid-row div[role=row] {
  display: flex ;
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

Tried Paul's fix and it worked but requires change to core code.  Also, our requirements called for showing the entire table on the page based on the data rather than a fixed height table with scroll.  So we couldn't use.

Instead, I worked around the issue by implementing a dynamic grid height solution.

Added ng-style to the grid as follows:

```
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" style="float:left" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination ng-style="gridHeight()" class="myGrid"></div>
```

Disabled grid scrolling:

```
    $scope.gridOptions.enableHorizontalScrollbar = 0;
    $scope.gridOptions.enableVerticalScrollbar = 0;
```

Wrote function gridHeight as follows (uses jQuery):

```
    $scope.gridHeight = function() {

      var outerHeight = 50; //buffer for things like pagination

      $('.ui-grid-row').each(function() {
        outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
      });

      $('.ui-grid-header').each(function() {
        outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
      });

      return { height: outerHeight+"px"};
    };
```

This satisfied our requirements.